# How to pass ID from main view to another view to partial view

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a main view of an Employee Profile having only a summary or general info about the Employee. I have a Details option in there that when clicked, would redirect to another view (page). On that page (i'll call it Details page), there is a partial view w/c is a table.

As of now, the partial view displays all the employee records w/c should not be the case. It should only retrieve the details of the employee that was chosen from the main view.

Any suggestion on how I could do this?

THIS IS THE MAIN VIEW

```
<table id="tbl_empProfile" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EMP_ID)</th>
           <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EMP_NUMBER)</th>
           <th> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FULL_NAME)</th>
           ....
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
         <tr>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EMP_ID)</td>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EMP_NUMBER)</td>
             <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FULL_NAME)</td>
             ....
             <td>
                 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "UpdateProfile", new { id = item.EMP_ID }) |
                 @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsProfile", new { id = item.EMP_ID }) |
                 @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.EMP_ID })
             </td>
         </tr>
     }
 </table>
```

DETAILS PAGE (ANOTHER VIEW)

```
@model ebms_2.Models.EmpProfile
....
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EMP_ID)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EMP_NUMBER, "Employee Number")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.EMP_NUMBER, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EMP_NUMBER)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.EMP_NUMBER)

    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FULL_NAME, "Employee Name")
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FULL_NAME, new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FULL_NAME, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.FULL_NAME)
}

<div class ="container">
    @Html.Partial("_EducationalBackground", Model.partialModel)
</div>
```

_Education_Background PARTIAL VIEW

```
@model IEnumerable<ebms_2.Models.EmpProfile>
@using ebms_2.Models.EmpProfile
@if (Model != null)
{
    <table id="tbl_empEduc" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.EMP_ID)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SCHOOL_NAME)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.YEAR_GRADUATED)</th>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.REMARKS)</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EMP_ID)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SCHOOL_NAME)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.YEAR_GRADUATED)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.REMARKS)</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
}
```

EmployeeProfileRepository

```
public List<EmpProfile> GetEmpEducation()
{
    connection();
    List<EmpProfile> empEducList = new List<EmpProfile>();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SP_LIST_EMP_EDUCATION", con);
    com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;      
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    con.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Close();
    // Bind EmpModel generic list using dataRow
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        empEducList.Add(new EmpProfile
        {
            EMP_ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["EMP_ID"]),
            SCHOOL_NAME = Convert.ToString(dr["SCHOOL_NAME"]),
            YEAR_GRADUATED = Convert.ToInt32(dr["YEAR_GRADUATED"]),
            REMARKS = Convert.ToString(dr["REMARKS"])
        });
    }
    return empEducList;
}
```

Comment: Show your code. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke already edited my question and included the code in it. Hope it can help you help me. Thanks! x

Comment: Unclear what yout asking. Are you wanting the `_Education_Background.cshtml` partial to display only Education information for the employee?

Comment: @StephenMuecke From the main view, I should be able to select a specific Employee Record, from there, I need to load the details of that employee to another view w/c is the Details view, inside the details view, there is a partial view w/c is the _Education_Background.cshtml, this should display the education background of the specific employee that was chosen from the main view.

Comment: But you already have a link (`@Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsProfile", new { id = item.EMP_ID })`)which is passing the employee ID to the `DetailsProfile(int id)` method. And if `partialModel` in `@Html.Partial("_EducationalBackground", Model.partialModel)` contains only the employees details then that's what it will display. Not sure where you having difficulties

Comment: And what is the point of your form in the `Details` page? (you cant edit anything and you don't even have a submit button)

Comment: @StephenMuecke But it still displays the Educational Background for all the Employee Records, do you think that the Stored Proc we used to list the Education Background had something to do with it?

Comment: You have not shown how your populating the `partialModel` property of your model :)

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke please checkout the Partial View code, scroll down and there you'll see the EmployeeProfileRepository thanks! :)

Comment: You have not shown how and where you calling that method, but best guess is in the `Details(int id)` method you need `model.partialModel = GetEmpEducation().Where(x => x.EMP_ID == id);`.But why in the world are you creating a `DataTable` and then creating a collection of your model from it. If you have a SP, just use a `DataReader` and populate your collection in a loop.

Comment: And unless you need a view displaying all education details, the modify your SP and method to pass the `ID` and just return what you need.

Comment: @StephenMuecke in the Details page, I have 4 other Partial Views aside from the _Educational_Background.cshtml

Comment: What difference will that make.